# Uncaught TypeError with React.js (GIPHY API)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm building a search engine (with React.js), where I can look for GIPHY gifs, using their API. When I type a word in the search bar, I get this error: **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: props.gifs.map is not a function
    at GifList (SelectedList.js:19)**

**The code where the API fetch occurs**:

```
import React from 'react'; //react library
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; //react DOM - to manipulate elements
import './index.css';
import SearchBar from './components/Search';
import GifList from './components/SelectedList';

class Root extends React.Component { //Component that will serve as the 
parent for the rest of the application.

constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        gifs: []
    }
    this.handleTermChange = this.handleTermChange.bind(this)
}

handleTermChange(term) {
   console.log(term);
    let url = 'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${term}&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC';
        fetch(url).
    then(response => response.json()).then((gifs) => {
          console.log(gifs);
          console.log(gifs.length);
          this.setState({
            gifs: gifs
          });
        });
    };  


render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar onTermChange={this.handleTermChange} />
        <GifList gifs={this.state.gifs} />
      </div>
    );
}
}

ReactDOM.render( <Root />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**The error comes from the code below:**

```
import React from 'react';
import GifItem from './SelectedListItem';

const GifList = (props) => {
  ===>const gifItems = props.gifs.map((image) => {<===
    return <GifItem key={image.id} gif={image} />
});

return (
    <ul>{gifItems}</ul>
  );
};

export default GifList;
```

**GifItem from ./SelectedListItem**:

```
import React from 'react';

 const GifItem = (image) => {
   return (
     <li>
       <img src={image.gif.url} />
     </li>
  )
 };

 export default GifItem;
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error (TypeError) is suggesting that the object `props.gifs` is not an array.

I would check to make sure `props.gif` is an array, and that you are actually calling `.map()` on the returned array of gifs from your AJAX request.

Comment: Can you provide an example, please? @kevvor

Comment: I have checked and it's in fact an array. The issue must come from somewhere else maybe. @kevvor

Answer (score 0):

How you call the api is wrong here because in, this.setState calling is wrong instead of writing gifs:gifs you should better call it as the code below sice using axios is very also fast:

```
handleTermChange = async (term) => {
const response = await axios.get(`http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${term}&limit=24&api_key=(YOUR APİ_KEY)
  this.setState({gifs:response.data.data})
}
```

you should also import axios to use this code.